# What Call-ID when we run Sofia status profile xxxxxx reg?

Tags: ios, voip, pjsip, gossip

I am trying to make an iOS app with **PJSIP**, I am using **GOSSIP wrapper** for that when i run the following command

```
"Sofia status profile xxxxxx reg"
```

to check the registered devices on server, i get following for each device. I was wondering about what is Call-ID parameter and if i can get this on device? if Yes then how?

> Call-ID:        mDWB.zJEvhcLSOnZcKTuTFbrduzO--0a
>   User:          xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>   Contact:        "" 
>   Agent:          Dringgg-Android
>   Status:         Registered(UDP)(unknown) EXP(2016-02-23 16:11:23)
>   EXPSECS(95)
>   Ping-Status:    Reachable Ping-Time:      0.00 Host:           srv1
>   IP:             xxxxxxxxxxxxx Port:           8080 Auth-User:
>   xxxxxxx Auth-Realm:     xxxxxxxxx MWI-Account:    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Answer (score 0):

> Call-ID header field (mandatory) is a dialog identifier and it's purpose is to
>   identify messages belonging to the same call/dialog. Such messages have the
>   same Call-ID identifier.

I'm not sure if you can get it when registering a user agent but it can be obtained when making a call using `pjsua_call_make_call` function, from the last parameter `p_call_id`

```
pj_status_t pjsua_call_make_call (pjsua_acc_id  acc_id,
                                  const pj_str_t *  dst_uri,
                                  const pjsua_call_setting *    opt,
                                  void *    user_data,
                                  const pjsua_msg_data *    msg_data,
                                  pjsua_call_id *   p_call_id 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

it can also be retrieved on callback method like 
:
on_call_state

here you get a struct pjsua_call_info.

in which ci.call_id can be found.